# How to find the third Taylor Polynomial of $f(x) = \sin(6x^{2})$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have pieces of understanding here but there are gaps that I cannot seem to make work to understand this.
I know that the generalize formula for a Taylor Polynomial and Taylor Series is:

$$ = \frac{f^{0}(a)}{0!}(x-a)^{0} + \frac{f^{1}(a)}{1!}(x-a)^{1} + \frac{f^{2}(a)}{2!}(x-a)^{2} + \frac{f^{3}(a)}{3!}(x-a)^{3} + \frac{f^{4}(a)}{4!}(x-a)^{4} + ...$$

So does that mean that to find the third Taylor polynomial I would take this expansion up from $0!$ to $3!$ ?

$$ = \frac{f^{0}(a)}{0!}(x-a)^{0} + \frac{f^{1}(a)}{1!}(x-a)^{1} + \frac{f^{2}(a)}{2!}(x-a)^{2} + \frac{f^{3}(a)}{3!}(x-a)^{3}$$

And then at the $f^{n}$'s I would put the appropriate derivative evaluated at 0 or some other specified value?

In my question it just asks for $P_{3}(x)$ and does not give a center value. But it must be '$0$' because I guessed on one part and turned out '$0$' was the correct answer. So when it says $P_{3}(x)$ it's assumed that it will be the $n$th derivative evaluated at the value $0$?

So would the process be something like the following?

$f^{0}(0) = \sin(6(0)^{2}) = 0$

$f^{1}(0) = \cos(6\cdot0^{2})\cdot2\cdot6\cdot0 = 0$

$f^{2}(0) = ...$

$f^{3}(0) = ...$

The derivatives get very messy and complex fast, so I think I am doing something wrong here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean tayor expand to order 3. There is also no need to mess with derivatives. Since 
$$
\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$$
is well known.

We can plug in $6x^2$ and get
$$
\sin (6x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(6x)^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}
$$
and you want 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^3\frac{(-1)^n(6x)^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}
$$
which will approximate $\sin 6x^2$ up to a factor that is proportional to $x^{18}$